# Pandas set_Value with DatetimeIndex [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add the row-wise result from a function into my dataframe using 
`df.set_Value`.

`df` in the format :

```
    Count   DTW
DateTime        
2015-01-16  10  0
2015-01-17  28  0
```

Using `df.setValue`

```
dw.set_Value(idx, 'col', dtw) # idx and dtw are int values

TypeError: cannot insert DatetimeIndex with incompatible label
```

How do I solve this error or what alternative method with comparable efficiency is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have `Series`, not `DataFrame`, so use [`Series.set_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.set_value.html) with index converted to `datetime`

```
dw = pd.Series([-2374], index = [pd.to_datetime('2015-01-18')])
dw.index.name = 'DateTime'
print (dw)
DateTime
2015-01-18   -2374
dtype: int64

print (dw.set_value(pd.to_datetime('2015-01-19'), 1))
DateTime
2015-01-18   -2374
2015-01-19       1
dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (dw.set_value(pd.datetime(2015, 1, 19), 1))
DateTime
2015-01-18   -2374
2015-01-19       1
dtype: int64
```

More standard way is use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (dw)
            Count  DTW
DateTime              
2015-01-16     10    0
2015-01-17     28    0

dw.ix[1, 'DTW'] = 10
#dw.DTW.iloc[1] = 10
print (dw)
            Count  DTW
DateTime              
2015-01-16     10    0
2015-01-17     28   10
```

Comment: I'm getting the idx value from a range so I wanted to allocate it directly using an int value, I think this created a problem with the index as it is not in numerical order but is instead a DateTime index. I hope this clarified my question

Comment: So do you have first index with `int` and `datetime` values? Or need overwrite some value, e.g. `28` in sample? Or add new row?

Comment: I want to set a value on an existing row that has a datetime index, is there an iterable that I could use to get datetime index as opposed to int?

Comment: Do you think something like `dw.DTW.iloc[1] = 10` ?

Comment: For some reason that escaped me, Thank you @jezrael that worked